# How do I stop MS Word from adding a Table of Contents when I type the word "table" in my text and press Enter?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I type "table" in text in a MS Word document and then hit enter, it automatically adds a Table of Contents, and also adds a number of (unwanted) styles in my ribbon-style list.

(Note: If I type "table" followed by two spaces, the "Table of Contents" highlight in the image below goes away, and hitting enter does not result in a table being generated.  So it's almost like an "Auto-Correct" feature, but when I looked in Auto-Correct for "table", there was no entry.)

I'm guessing it's an option somewhere, but I've looked all over in Word itself, and also online, but I'm not finding anything about this.

(I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise, and MS Office 365. )

I've included an image of what happens when I type "table",  just so you can see what is happening.

This is a screen-grab of my word doc

[image]

Comment: What version of Word and Windows (or other OS) are you using?

Comment: My apology...  I meant to include that.  Windows 10 Enterprise, and MS Office 365.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is "AutoComplete" indicating a Building Block (likely AutoText) named Table of Contents.

Open your Building Blocks Organizer (`Insert > Quick Parts > Building Block Organizer`).

Click in the column for Name to sort by name and look for an entry that starts with the word TABLE.

Edit the properties of that entry to give it a different name. When you are done, you will be asked if you want to change that entry.

[image: screenshot of Building Blocks Organizer]

*Chances are good that this is an **AutoText** entry.*

When you close Word, you will be asked if you want to save changes to a template holding building blocks. The answer is "yes."

### How did this happen?

When you go to save a building block, especially AutoText, Word gives it a default name of the start of text in the building block. **This is seldom the name you want.** Here is [my writing on Building Blocks and AutoText](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete).

It is likely that you, or the person who prepared your template, set up a TOC with that heading, selected it, and saved it as a Building Block. Had this entry been [saved to the template Building Blocks.dotx as an addition to the Table of Contents Gallery](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#AddTOCGallery), it would not give the AutoComplete and action with the Enter key.

If it is in the document template, though, you get the AutoComplete and in the document template may have been the best place to store it. Here is [my writing on where building blocks can be stored](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks).

Here is my writing on the [AutoComplete feature with AutoText and other Building Blocks](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/autocomplete-for-autotext-and-other-building/a37369a5-b112-471c-a327-a5aa0c0a40f4?tm=1667850080460).

Comment: PERFECT!!!   You pointed me to EXACTLY the right spot, and YES, it appears that unbeknownst to me, my company added an "Add-In" that included that "table" add-on...

Thanks SO MUCH for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. You might suggest to the person responsible for the Add-In that a better name might be @Table or _Table so it will not be triggered by accident. (You still have to press the Enter key, at least.)